# Link sharing is not working when native facebook application is installed

Tags: android, facebook

In my application I have a share button which shares the application link to Facebook wall.This is how I am doing it.

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());

        ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(
                        Uri.parse(PreferenceManager
                                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(
                                        getActivity()
                                                .getApplicationContext())
                                .getString("referral_only_url", "")))
                .build();

        ShareDialog.show(getActivity(), content);
```

Now the problem is that this works fine with web dialog if Facebook native application is not installed in device but if native Facebook app is installed this fails with a error saying:

> WE ARE SORRY THIS POST IS NO LONGER AVAILABLE. IT MAY HAVE BEEN REMOVED

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes i do have the same problem i'm using facebook sdk 4.3 ...

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not using the same app name as Facebook app name .

```
   <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
        android:value="@string/app_name" />
```

Here `app_name` must be same as app name as you specified in `Facebook`

**Example  :**

If your app in facebook is registered as

> MyTest_Android

You have to use the same name as your

> MyTest_Android

If you try to change it,You"ll catch `FacebookException` in `onError()`

> Failed to authenticate the application because of app name mismatch.
>   Please check the application name configured by the dialog.